# tensor product of one-one linear maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, modules, tensor-products

> Let $f_1:M_1\to M_1'$ and $f_2:M_2\to M_2'$ be one-one linear maps, where $M_1,M_1',M_2,M_2'$ are free $R$-modules. Is $f_1\otimes f_2: M_1\otimes M_2\to M_1'\otimes M_2'$ defined by $$(f_1\otimes f_2)(x\otimes y)= f_1(x)\otimes f_2(y)$$
> a one-one linear map?

If $R$ is a field then this is true. This can be prove using the fact that any linearly independent subset of a vector space can be extended to a basis of the given vector space. Does a similar result - *Any linearly independent subset of a module can be extended to a basis of the module* - also holds for an arbitrary module?

Comment: Haven't tried, but, $M_1'$ and $M_2'$ are both free modules., is it possible for $M_1'\otimes M_2'=0$?

Comment: That similar result does not hold. Try the set {2} in the ring of integers considered as a module over itself.

Comment: @user26857 Tensoring with $0$ should not give any problems, or does it? Could you explain your comment?

Comment: Did I say something about tensoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a result like *Any linearly independent subset of a module can be extended to a basis of the module* does not generally hold, not even for free modules, see [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435373/can-we-extend-a-linearly-independent-list-in-a-f-g-module-of-a-commutative-ring).

The result more generally holds if $M'_1$ and $M_2$ or $M_1$ and $M'_2$ are flat, i.e. tensoring with these modules is an exact functor. In more down to earth terms: the tensor product is right exact, this means that given an epimorphism $P \to P'$ of $R$-modules, then tensoring with an arbitrary $R$-module $Q$ yields an epimorphism $P \otimes Q \to P' \otimes Q$. Tensoring is not in general left-exact, i.e. monomorphism are not necessarily taken to monomorphisms.

For this problem, notice that $f_1\otimes f_2$ can be decomposed as
$$
M_1 \otimes M_2 \overset{f_1 \otimes \text{id}}{\longrightarrow} M_1' \otimes M_2 \overset{\text{id} \otimes f_2}{\longrightarrow} M_1' \otimes M_2'.
$$
if we assume $M_1', M_2$ to be flat, then, by the above discussion, $f_1 \otimes \text{id}_{M_2}$ and $\text{id}_{M_1'} \otimes f_2$ are monomorphisms, hence so is $f_1\otimes f_2$.

Decomposing $f_1 \otimes f_2$ as $(\text{id}_{M_2'} \otimes f_1) \circ (f_2 \otimes \text{id}_{M_1})$ yields the same result for $M_2', M_1$ flat.

Free modules are flat, as are projective modules, so this result is true for huge (but admittedly very 'tame') classes of $R$-modules. I will try to think of some counterexamples for non-flat modules and edit this later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why are $f_1,f_2$ epi?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Oh well, I am sorry, turns out one-one does not mean 'bijective', but rather 'injective', this is my dumb mistake. The argument should still work without the whole discussion about epis. I will edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and preservation of isomorphisms is of course trivial, just because of functoriality.